# python integer argument value is not changing even though id() is same in calling and called functions

Tags: python, call-by-value

```
def func(x):
    print "inside function" ,id(x)
    x = 2
x = 50
print "outside function" ,id(x)
print 'Value of x before function call is', x
func(x)
print 'Value of x after function call is', x
```

output:

```
outside function 6486996
Value of x before function call is 50
inside function 6486996
Value of x after function call is 50
```

Assuming that `id()` gives memory location of object. Even though both are saving at the same location, if x value is changed in `func()`, it is not effected outside.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, but the `id(x)` call in the function references the global x that was passed to the function, but the `x = 2` creates a new local x. Try this:

```
def func(x):
    print "inside function", id(x)
    x = 2
    print "still inside function", id(x)

x = 50
print "outside function" , id(x)
print 'Value of x before function call is', x
func(x)
print 'Value of x after function call is', x
```

**typical output**

```
outside function 168950596
Value of x before function call is 50
inside function 168950596
still inside function 168951172
Value of x after function call is 50
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want know more about it, i think u need understand basic python fully.

point about your question:

**mutable object as parameter**

The function gets a reference to that object and could mutate it, but if you re-bind the reference in the method,  outer scope know nothing,after done, the outer reference would still point the original object.

**immutable object as parameter**

Still can't re-bind the outer reference, and can't even mutate this object.

update for comments: so u pass x(Integer immutable) to function call, you can't mutate this object. and u you re-bind the x refer in the function, outer scope know nothing,after done, the outer reference would still point the original integer 50 object.

Comment: As re-bind is what happens here, no need to distinguish between mutable and immutable in this context.

Comment: Also, integers are immutable in Python, which is why they can be interned.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment usually changes the binding between name and object (if you don't do sth like `x = x`, of course). It doesn't do any alterations on the object (which wouldn't work on `int`s anyway as they are immutable, but just as a side note)

So in this case your `x` inside the function points to the `50` object until you change it. Then it points to a different object. The object itself is not affected.

To point out what happens step by step:

- outside `x` points to int object with value 50
- function call: inside `x` points to same object
- inside `x` is changed to point to different object, having value 2
- return: outside `x` still points to 50.